# UISearchbar TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uisearchbar

When I type any character in Search bar, a Table View automatically appears, is there anyway that can prevent Table View not to appear automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're using - 'Search Bar and Search Display Controller' (in IB) , it comes with a UITableView , if you just need the Search Bar, then drag 'Search Bar' from the Object Library (IB).

if you do want to decide when to display the table, you can toggle the UITableView visibility:

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.hidden = TRUE;
```